# Openshift - Passenger shows env variables on fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, openshift

I am deploying a Rails app on Openshift, and I had a crash recently. I realized with horror that Passenger was giving users an error page containing all the debug info, including the environment variables (containing for instance all the credentials for the mailing service, amazon S3, etc...). How can I choose not to display such information?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think you'll be able to change this without creating a custom cartridge that wouldn't utilize passenger. However, I think that this is an important bug to file here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=OpenShift%20Online. Once you file one go ahead and post a comment and I'll see what I can do to expedite it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug in Phussion Passenger OpenShift internally is using, since [docs](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerFriendlyErrorPages) specifically say that `PassengerAppEnv` set to production, which we do by default, should lead to showing just simple 'Something Went Wrong' error page. To make it working again I've added conditional turning those pages on/off with [this PR](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/pull/6072), something like that:

```
<% unless ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "development" %>
PassengerFriendlyErrorPages off
<% end %>
```